# Vagrant (Magestead) & Modman symlink issue

Tags: modman, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant & Magestead to set up a testing environment for a module. The module has been symlink'ed on my machine (so, not in the VM) into the `magento/` directory that is shared with the VM.

If I `vi` the linked module XML file on my machine, I can see it has the correct content.

If I `vagrant ssh` into the box though and do the same, the file is empty. I can also see none of the module files are showing in the VM; even though the / directory is present - it's empty.

Has anyone set something like this up before?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Modman working with your VM you will need to run it from within the VM as the symlinks it creates need to be relative to the guest machine not the host machine.

Magestead comes with Modman pre installed, you should run Modman inside the VM to fix the symlinks.